# What should I return when using websocket apigateway with lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I deployed a websocket apigateway and put a lambda to integrate with `$default` route. The lambda definition is:

```golang
func ApiEventHandler(ctx context.Context, event events.APIGatewayWebsocketProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error){

  return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{Body: "Invalid request", StatusCode: 400}, fmt.Errorf("Invalid request, no body found")
}
```

When I send a message to the websocket connection, I get this error response:

```
 {"message": "Internal server error", "connectionId":"AZ-dVfPcSwMCF9A=", "requestId":"AZ-dhHRFywMFziA="}
```

Regardless what error message I response, the client always receives `Internal server error`.

I know I can use management api to post a response to client with a customised payload. Is it the right way to response error? I'd like to understand the behaviour of the error response from lambda. Is there a way to customise the error payload?

I am using `go` but the question is same for any other language.

Comment: Did you check CloudWatch Logs for the lambda for any errors?

Comment: the lambda doesn't have any error in cloudwatch.

Comment: Does the Lambda get triggered, according to cloudwatch? [This page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-how-to-call-websocket-api-connections.html) gives an example in Node. And maybe try returning 200 as per example first, before exploring the behavior for 400 and others.